# Nginx + php7.0-fpm(No input file specified.)

Tags: php, nginx

Пытаюсь открыть php файл(Hello World!) в браузере.Chrome выдает(No input file specified.) В логах php7.0-fpm.log ошибок нет.В логах nginx пишет:

```
::1 - - [24/Oct/2016:18:02:15 +0300] "GET /certunia/helloworld.php
HTTP/1.1" 404 56 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143
Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
```

файл default:

```
server
{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /
    {

    }

    location /certunia/
    {
            index index.php index.html;
            alias /home/certunia/php;

            location ~ \.php$
            {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/certunia/php$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: теоретически, не хватает слэша после php `/home/certunia/php/$fastcgi_script_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

     location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }





    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Помогло,спасибо.